# How to align a single Gutenberg block button in WP 5.5.3?

Tags: block-editor, buttons

With some WP update, the single block button suddenly disappeared from Gutenberg blocks. Now, we only have a block 'Buttons' element (don't know why actually. I reckon' that >80 per cent of all uses are single button scenarios...).

So, how can I adjust alignment from within the editor, if I have only a single button? Say, I need to center the button. Can't find any alignment options with the element anymore either, as people suggested [here](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/single-button-disappeared-from-gutenberg/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. select the entire 'buttons' block
   [image: select the entire 'buttons' block by to block toolbar, list view, choose buttons]
2. once the entire buttons block is selected,
   [image: go to the justify toolbar icon, and select how to center]

For future reference, [the wordpress.com button article is usually current](https://wordpress.com/support/wordpress-editor/blocks/buttons-block/) although it is currently out of date at the moment.